# Why isn't my controller displaying my view after I make an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, get

I'm calling my controller action 'Results' from an Ajax call in javascript but the page isn't refreshing or going to the view "Search"! It stays on the page I'm currently on.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Results(string searchQuery) //, DateTime classDate)
    {
        var viewModel = new YogaSpaceListViewModel
        {
            SearchQuery = searchQuery
        };
        return View("Search", viewModel);
    }
```

```js
 $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "/home/results",
   data: {
     searchQuery: searchQuery
   }
 }).
 fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
 });
```

Comment: Because ajax calls stay on the same page. Your method should be returning a partial view (`return PartialView(..);`) not a view, and you need to handle the ajax success callback to update the DOM with the partial that the controller returned - e.g. `success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }`

Comment: changing to PartialView won't help either unless there is a success functioni handler with something placing the response on the page like you suggested - just wanted to point that out

Comment: most of your questions have a good amount of good answers with none as accepted, please select answers that help as accepted and vote those accordingly .  People take time to help , and also it will help future people with the same problem to know which answer best solved the problem for you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a little confused about what an AJAX call is ,  these requests will not send the user to another page, and the way you have it written - it actually wont do anything at all except make the call.

```
 $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "/home/results",
   data: {
     searchQuery: searchQuery
   },
   success: function(data){
    // here is what is called on a successful response from the server
    // it is now your job to do something with the response.
    // the response will be found in the `data` object
   }
 }).
```

what you would do is place the data from the response into your html somewhere ,  something like the comments would work just fine.

```
  $('#myDiv').html(data);
```

instead of doing all that , I would recommend just something like this, as it seems what you were going for:

```
   window.location  = "/Home/Results?searchQuery=" + searchQuery;
```

this will send the user to the new page that you wanted them to go to.